# R: Remove outline from geom_col() and export as pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot find a way to remove the outline that appears around each column in geom_col(), specifically when exporting as a pdf (need vector graphic).

Passing `col=NA` or `linewidth=0` should hide the outlines but doesn't seem to be working.  If I export as a png, the column outlines are gone even if these arguments are not included.

I want to represent each data point as a bar: I do not want to smooth my data with a combination of `geom_line()+ geom_area()`.  However, the outline around each column is distracting and I want to remove them.

Thanks for any insights!

**NOTE:**  I could not upload a pdf, so I converted the pdf to a high-res png after exporting from R.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Position = rep(1:300, 3),
  Signal = sample(1:30, 900, replace=TRUE),
  Group = c(rep("A", 300), rep("B", 300), rep("C", 300))
  )

plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df, aes(x=Position, y=Signal, fill=Group), col=NA, size=0) +
  facet_grid(Group~.)

ggsave("~/Desktop/plot.pdf", plot, device = "pdf")
ggsave("~/Desktop/plot.png", plot, device = png, dpi=300)

# I've also tried cairo - similar outcome
ggsave("~/Desktop/plot_cairo.pdf", plot, device = cairo_pdf)
```

**UPDATE** Adding the `width=1` argument *mostly* resolves the issue (Thanks Gregor, Artëm, and Zé).  Hairline outlines persist at columns where the adjacent y-value is different, whereas adjacent columns with the same y-value have no outline as desired.

`col=NULL` and `linewidth=0` arguments do not appear to have any effect on the pdf output.

```
plot2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df, aes(x=Position, y=Signal, fill=Group), width=1, col=NA, linewidth=0) +
  facet_grid(Group~.)
ggsave("~/Desktop/plot2.pdf", plot2, device = "pdf")

# Omitting col and linewidth arguments
plot3 <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df, aes(x=Position, y=Signal, fill=Group), width=1) +
  facet_grid(Group~.)
ggsave("~/Desktop/plot3.pdf", plot3, device = "pdf")
```

**Plot PDF VERSION** (Click image to Zoom-in)
[image: PDF VERSION]

**Plot PNG VERSION** (Click image to Zoom-in)
[image: PNG VERSION]

**UPDATE: Plot2** (Click image to Zoom-in)
[image: Plot2]

**UPDATE: Plot3** (Click image to Zoom-in)
[image: Plot3]

Comment: Which outline you are referring to? Both your pdf and png version looked the same? Are you referring to the background of the graphs?

Comment: Try setting `width = 1` in you `geom_col()`. I think the default is 0.9, which is small enough of a gap that the `png` rounds it away, but in a vector format like PDF it's visible.

Comment: Gregor, this got it much closer to removing column outlines. There are still hairline white outlines, but this will work for me.  Just curious - why do we set width to 1 instead of 0 here?

Comment: Web, the white outlines around each column are only visible in the pdf image (first image), and you have to click on the image to enlarge in order to be able to see.

Comment: The width is the width of the bar, as a fraction of the data resolution. So 1 should be full width bars, 0 would be no bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ggplot puts spaces between cols and bars, which is 0.1 of their width (see help: `??ggplot2::geom_col`). So you should put 100% of the width.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
    geom_col(data = df, aes(x=Position, y=Signal, fill=Group), width = 1) +
    facet_grid(Group~.)
```

However, they will be separated graphical objects, keet in in mind if you want to use this vector image in Corel Draw, Adobe Illustrator etc, so you probably shuld consider geom_area or geom_step functions, bellow:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>% 
    mutate(Position1 = Position - 1) %>% 
    pivot_longer(names_to = NULL, values_to = "Position", -c("Signal", "Group"))

ggplot(df1, aes(Position, Signal, fill = Group)) + 
    geom_area() +
    facet_grid(Group~.)
```

Additionally:

- `size` argument is no longer supported, use `linewidth` instead
- argument `col` is also meaninless here

Comment: `col` is not meaningless at all, that is the issue

Comment: @Artëm, can you expand on the effects that the columns being separate graphical objects will have when using the pdf/vector inside Adobe Illustrator?  I'm new to this.
Including `width=1` does improve the problem, but it isn't perfect. See my updated post for an image (updating shortly).

@Zé, Including/Excluding `col` and `linewidth` arguments have no effect on the pdf output in my hands.

Answer (score 0):

TL,DR: `colour=Group` and `width=1` fixed this. Explanation below:

When you render the plot as a PDF file, it is rendered in vector format, so each column is a different polygon.  If you open the file on Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator you'll find some important things:

- `colour=NA` makes the columns' polygons have no stroke colour (i.e. the outline is transparent.
- Each polygon *does* have a stroke width of 4/3 of a pixel (1.3333px), which means that the stroke *is there*, even if transparent.  This means that `linewidth=0` (`size=` has been deprecated) doesn't do what you expect it to do.

So the simple solution is: draw the stroke with the same colour as the fill:
`aes(..., fill = Group, colour = Group)`.  As also noted on other answers and comments,  you'll also need `width=1` to make sure the columns are rendered back to back.

Comment: I still see hairline white outlines in several of the columns when setting `color=Group` and `width=1`.  Also, in practice I use manual fill and color scale because I overlay a geom_line() in each facet, so would ideally find a solution that doesn't require the color argument.

`plot4 <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df, aes(x=Position, y=Signal, fill=Group, color=Group), width=1) +
  facet_grid(Group~.)
ggsave("~/Desktop/plot4.pdf", plot4, device = "pdf")`

Comment: You can have `color = NA` for the `geom_col` layer and still have color in other layers.

Comment: If I set it to `color=Group` as is done here, it pulls the colors from my custom color vector.  I agree that `color=NA` would work, but this solution seems to require that I specify the fill and color arguments.